# detect translate3d change like on scroll function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a `script` that creates a smooth scrolling effect with removing the original browser scrollbar and changing the contents position with css `translate3d`. Now I want to include a script that detects that translate3d change to set a css rule `on` every `scroll` change. Here's my example code:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  $('myDiv').css('color', 'red').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Now instead of calling `.on('scroll', ...)` i want to call something like `.on('translate3dchange', ...)`. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: first make sure that the ***script*** you got does not offer that functionality, for example an event callback in which you can hook your code.

Comment: Well I thought so too ... but before I go throu the 3k lines of code, I wanted to make sure that there wouldn't be a faster/easier way to achive what i need. I guess I have no choise than... @GabrielePetrioli

Comment: Doesn't that lib have documentation ?

Comment: It does but it doen't include what i need ...

Comment: added an answer with a solution, but if you could name/link to the plugin we might be able to come up with a better solution.

Comment: ok ... i will take a look into that. Here is the Plugin im using: https://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/ I changed the jsfile a bit. But in general it shoudln't be much different than the original. Thank you for you help sofar! @GabrielePetrioli

Comment: The plugin docs indicate that there is the functionality you want through the [addListener](https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar/blob/develop/docs/api.md#scrollbaraddlistener) API method.

Comment: Oh ... I haven't looked at that API site yet ... that should work. I will keep this in mind for future. Thank you!

Comment: I got one more question thoe ... how to I implement that addListener and replace it with the jQuery 'scroll'? I can't realy figure this out by myself >.< @GabrielePetrioli

Comment: `var scrollbar = Scrollbar.init(elem);
scrollbar.addListener(function(){/*do what you want in here*/});`

Comment: I can't thank you enough! That worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the changes happen in the `style` attribute and not through css classes then you could use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) but you would have to manually check if the changed property was the `translate` or which ever specific one you want.

```js
const test = document.querySelector('.test');
let counter = 0;
// mimick an action altering the style of the .test element
setInterval(function() {
  test.style.transform = `translate(${++counter}px)`;
}, 500);


//const MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
const transformObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  const styleMutation = mutations[0];
  const oldValue = styleMutation.oldValue.split(';').find(prop => prop.startsWith('transform') || prop.startsWith(' transform'));
  const current = styleMutation.target.style.transform;
  const old = ((oldValue && oldValue.split(':')[1]) || '').trim();
  if (current !== old) {
    // the translate property has been changed 
    // do what you want here
    console.log(current, old);
  }
});

transformObserver.observe(test, {
  attributes: true, //configure it to listen to attribute changes
  attributeFilter: ['style'], //configure it to limit the listening only to the style attribute
  attributeOldValue: true // keep the old value so we can compare;
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transform: translate(1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="test" style="background-image:url('somevalue');color:red;"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62437585/13399106